# willPerformHTTPRedirection not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

I use next code to create session and run task:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration * config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
VPNCheckResultRequest *request = [VPNCheckResultRequest message];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
[task resume];
```

But delegate's method `willPerformHTTPRedirection` not called. Where could be a problem, thank you.

Comment: Did you check that all these created objects are not null, using the debugger, step by step ?

Comment: @NoonanRosenblum yes, I check all twice.